# Is "what would you rather she does?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Someone said "what would you rather her do?". It didn't sound correct to me. So, I said it's "what would you rather she does?". Someone else said it isn't correct either and said it's "what would you rather have her do?". This sounded better to me, but I want to know if I was wrong.

Comment: What was the preceding sentence?

Comment: "correctness" questions are more appropriate on [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: She was going to have a meeting tomorrow, so she had to reschedule her lecture, because she's a lecturer. But, it was not going to be okay with some students. So, one of them asked one of the whiners, "what would you rather her do?".

Comment: Related / possible duplicate *earlier* questions about this aspect of English include [Syntax of "Would Rather"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371727/) and ["would rather" + subject + past subjunctive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169250/) and [Is 'I would rather...' without an infinitive immediately following it correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73891/) It's one for pedants to have a field day with! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult for one who is not a trained linguistics/grammar expert to sort this one out.
However my native ear tells me that all of the following are idiomatic, and in daily use in GB.

***What would you rather she do***. (Some might argue that *does* could be substituted here, but I certainly prefer *do*)

***What would you rather her do.***

***What would you rather have her do***.

Comment: I'm fine with all three verb forms in *What would you rather she **do / does / did**?* in the cited context, but I can't go along with your second example above (though the final one is fine with ***have***).

Comment: If you find #2 "okay", how do you react to *Where would you rather **him** go?* and *What would you rather **me** say?* Your "her" version puts me in mind of Somerset dialect. But I can't get my head round those "him" and "me" alternatives at all, even though syntactically they seem to be doing the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it not simply elision? The "have" is still there, in all cases, but just not spoken. However I do rather agree with you that the shorter versions come across as a bit downmarket.  My own original dialect was Norfolk which - as a county both linguistically and culturally of the south - has more in common with Somerset than it does with neighbouring Lincolnshire, which is linguistically northern. So perhaps my affinity for #2 is down to something I heard with a pitchfork in my hand.

Comment: I guess it's up to you how you "internally rationalise" the syntax of #2. Obviously it's somehow "acceptable" to you, or you wouldn't have written it. If you put it down to *elision*, doesn't that suggest you should also be familiar with a kind of slurred "intermediate" version between #2 and #3 *(What would you rather've her do?)* In my experience, elided words like that usually had and often retain a half-hearted attempt to semi-articulate the "missing" element. But personally I find that particular ***'ve*** almost impossible to generate - it certainly doesn't sound / feel natural to me!

Comment: ...anyway, I'm terrifically glad to see that *you* find #2 acceptable. I'm not consciously aware that I've ever heard it myself - but sometimes I'm quite capable of simply not noticing some usage that doesn't make sense to me (unless and until I've heard it so often it's impossible to ignore! :) So I might have just dismissed that first sentence in OP's text as a meaningless example of "Funny things non-native speakers say". Whereas in fact it's obviously an "authentic" (albeit imho "exotic") form lurking among the natives!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two (of many more) ways to express the sentiment:

> 1. What would you rather have her do?

and

> 2. What would you rather she did?

Comment: What is your answer to the Q., which was "Is 'what would you rather she does?' grammatically correct?"?

Comment: The answer is no. I thought that was pretty obvious, but now I realize I was wrong.

Comment: I actually thought your answer was 'Yes', and that you were suggesting two further options.

Comment: @TrevorD: I'm terribly sorry. I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **rather her do** is grammatical.

Compare **[rather *me* do](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rather%20me%20do%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)**.

A pronoun in the objective case is licensed by the verb **rather**.

This is also valid:

What would you rather she say?

Comment: _Rather_ is not a verb, but an adverb. “What would you rather her do” is completely ungrammatical to me, and I wouldn’t actually have thought it was grammatical anywhere, but the quotes you link to make a strong case that this isn’t so. I suppose it’s a case of _would_ licensing an infinitival phrase complement with an overt subject for some, but not for others.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: IMO **rather**  has been reanalyzed as a verb in such constructions.  Compare: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20rather%20you%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: That seems unlikely to me. If so, it’s a very peculiar one, at least. I am not aware of any other verb in the English language that has no tensed forms and cannot appear as the matrix verb in a clause. There are no such forms as _rathers_ and _rathered_ that I’ve ever heard of, and a number of other matrix verb tests (passivisation, tags, etc.) also fail. I can’t think of anything that would indicate that _rather_ **has** been reanalysed as a verb. _I rather you [verb]_ is much more easily explained as colloquial deletion of _’d_ (cf. _you better/best go_).

Comment: As a defective verb.

Comment: Just because some speakers get confused between the nominative and the objective case, it doesn't mean that us can use whichever one us wants. The overwhelming majority of English speakers say *rather I do*. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+you+rather+I+do%2Crather+me+do%2Crather+I+do&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20you%20rather%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crather%20me%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crather%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'd argue that this is not a case of confusion of case.

Comment: Even as a defective verb, _rather_ would be extremely unusual. It would have to be reanalysed as an auxiliary verb to even partly fit (simple negation without _do_-support), and even then it wouldn’t fit properly. **No** other verb, auxiliary or not, requires an _auxiliary verb_ to form interrogatives, but _rather_ would: _I will go_ ≈ _I rather go_ → neg. _I will not go_ ≈ _I rather not go_ → int. _Will I go?_ ≈ _*Rather I go?_ (and also _*Do I rather go?_). It would simply fit neither the morphological nor the syntactic pattern of **any other verb**.

Comment: Native speakers don't process it as an adverb.

Comment: Also, I question the claim that objective pronouns are “fairly widespread” after _rather_. I have certainly never heard it, and Ngram and Google Books results are both dwarfed by subjective forms. (_What would you have me do_ is completely different – the objective pronoun there is a complement of _have_, which is happy to accept overt-subject infinitival complements; cf. _I had him do the laundry_.)

Comment: I'm saying that for some contemporary speakers **rather** is much like **would have** there.  "What would you have me do?" can be paraphrased as "What do you want me to do then?" Use of the objective pronouns with **rather** is quite common in AmE.

Comment: I can assure you that this native speaker **does** process it as an adverb and absolutely not as a verb. And apart from the comparatively few examples of people mixing up subject- and object-form pronouns, I have never seen any indication that other native speakers do not also process it as an adverb. If _rather_ is like _have_ in that example, how do you explain _What would you rather have me do?_ then?

Comment: I acknowledge adverbial **rather**, but I don't think the speakers who use the objective pronoun with **rather** are processing it adverbially.

Comment: In that case, it becomes a matter of certain people reanalysing _rather_ (and _better_, _best_, _sooner_, _[just] as soon_, etc.) as a verb only in one or two very specific constructions, while still processing it as an adverb elsewhere. There’s probably no way to disprove that that is the case, but it seems very unlikely to me. I think they’re more likely to just be mixing up the _have_ + infinitival complement construction with the subordinate clause construction (_Would you rather have me do…_ + _Would you rather I do…_ → _Would you rather me do…_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: TRomano is correct that at least some speakers have reanalyzed "rather" as a verb. See the quote in my answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/688/is-rather-shifting-to-become-a-verb/450139#450139 Forms with verbal suffixes like "would have rathered" are attested.

Comment: @sumelic That is fascinating. I cannot recall ever hearing any of the constructions mentioned on that page (except for the ones that can be seen as simple _’d_-deletion) and it seems totally bizarre to me, but apparently not to certain AmE speakers. And as that article says, verbal _rather_ does indeed seem to be unlike any other verb in the language. How utterly weird.

Comment: '  “What would you rather her do” is completely ungrammatical to me, '. Not for me! Regardless, the idiom *would rather* itself licences its own complements which can not only be subjunctive (as is possible but less likely in UK and probable in US), but also tensed clauses and even NPs, which would be impossible if these were complements of the modal auxiliary *would*. For example, I'm sure you find the following ok: *I would rather she left* or *I would rather you than me*, for example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sorry, didn't see this post was several years old!

Answer (score -1):

Turning to old reliable Will Shakespeare (in *As You Like It*)

```
   ...Truly, I would 
The gods had made thee poetical.
```

The verb in this problem is "would". "Rather" is simply an adverb, with no particular consequence.

An Elizabethan-ish dialogue:

```
I would she had done something else.
What would you she had done?
But soft! She is still doing that terrible thing.  
What would you she were doing?
Ah, she has stopped and asks now for guidance.
What would you she do?
```

Put in "rather," well, as you like it.

Comment: I'd rather she had done something else is past tense.

Comment: @Lambie The doing is in the past; the "would-ing" is in the present. I was just trying to show the verb choice for "to do" in relation to when the offending behavior occurs.

Comment: It does not correspond to the question as asked.

Comment: Let's let Jackson decide if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Ricky that ***what would you rather have her do?*** and ***what would you rather she did?*** are the only correct options with the construction "would rather".

Here's why: Because there are two constructions with "would rather".

---

**1st construction:** Pronoun + would rather + bare infinitive

So following that construction, the sentence *"what would you rather have her do?"* is 100% correct. Rearrange it as so:

"You would rather **have** her do what?"--> pronoun (you) + would rather + bare infinitive (have)

---

**2nd construction:** Pronoun 1 + would rather + pronoun 2 + past simple

Following the second construction, the sentence *"what would you rather she did?"* is also 100% correct. Rearrange it as so:

"You would rather she **did** what?"--> pronoun 1 (you) + would rather + pronoun 2 (she) + past simple (did)

---

Here is a website that explains well: https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/would-rather

Comment: The second version is technically an irrealis use as in *I’d rather she **were** here*, but you can't see that in the morphology of any verb except *be*. It's a vestige of the old past subjunctive.

Comment: Yes, I wrote "past simple" since the conjugation of the past subjunctive is basically the one of the past simple except that "was" becomes "were". British English also tends to use "was" instead of "were" for the construction "would rather + pronoun", here is an example from the Cambridge dictionary "would you rather I wasn’t honest with you?" while Americans tend to use "were" for this particular construction as well as others.

Answer (score -1):

The "I'd rather" shows that the speaker was talking about a (preferred) *hypothetical* situation. An irrealis form of the verb is therefore required. Two possibilities.

If the speaker wanted to ask about a preference for her future action, then it's "What would you rather she do?", just as the person had said, as reported in the OP.

If they wanted to ask about a preference for her past action, then it's "What would you rather she had done?".

"... she does?" (as suggested by the OP) and "... she did?" are incorrect. They are ordinary present and past tense forms, respectively, not irrealis forms.

Answer (score -2):

Examples of subject + would rather

- I'd rather he leave now. Or: I'd rather he left now.
- I'd rather he do the work now. Or: I'd rather he did the work now.
- What would you rather she do? Or: What would you rather she did?
- I'd rather he left now. [also]
- I'd rather he did the work now. [also]
- What would you rather she did? [also]

she does and her do don't work here.

The third-person singular s or es morpheme is not used after "would rather": subject ][I,we, etc.] would rather.

The choices are present simple without the third person singular morphemes (s or es) or simple past.

Real World Examples:

**Arsenal can’t win for losing**
20
**What would you rather they do: something or nothing?**[What would you rather they do?](https://theshortfuse.sbnation.com/2017/6/28/15887490/arsenal-transfer-rumor-thomas-lemar-club-cant-win-for-losing)

"Seriously - read what you typed. By far the biggest element of fuel is tax. The government should reduce the tax. And pay for what how???? Sadly the only means of raising revenue is.... tax. What would you rather they do? Shut your local hospital to pay for your drive down the motorway? Jeez."

[what would you rather they do?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/nickrobinson/2011/03/but_will_it.html)

"The public has indicated that they would rather he do this than increase taxes."
[would rather he do](https://www.express.co.uk/comment/columnists/martin-townsend/141808/Martin-Townsend-A-word-from-the-Editor)

Followed by simple past:

But Labour Leader Jeremy Corbyn told ITV News that he would "have a discussion" with Rosena Allin-Khan, who is a shadow minister, about her appearance at the rally: "She's entitled to her point of view. I would rather she and every other Labour MP spent today and tomorrow and Tuesday concentrating solely on making sure we defeat this deal."

[would rather plus simple past](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-46497531)

Firstly, according to 3,000 voters asked by the website Politico, 47 per cent of voters want Theresa May to compromise and reach a deal with the European Union, compared to 35 per cent who would rather she walked away without one. Indeed, 53 per cent of voters to 47 would rather we stayed in the European Union than exited with no deal in place.
https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/theresa-may-conservatives-brexit-no-deal-politics-westminster-leadership-a8618456.html

Comment: _-s_ is the third person **singular** morpheme, not plural.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yep, I dyslexiaed myself. I have fixed it.

Comment: I searched Google Books for the sequence [***what would you rather he***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22what+would+you+rather+he%22), and got back 6 pages of results. Just looking at the first page, I see contextually relevant examples of "Past" Tense *(**believed**)*, true Subjunctive *(**do**)*, and "Present" Tense *(**does**)*. Disregarding misplaced pedantry, I'd say they're all fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Google books does not speak. "What would you rather he does". is non-standard. If you want to use does and teach does here, be my guest. I would advise against it and would mark it as non-standard. Like I always say, it's all about internalizing stuff. Books with hits show nothing at all.

Comment: As you presumably know, I have little time for grammarians' notions of "non-standard". I'm firmly in the "descriptive linguistics" camp, so it's quite enough for me to find examples of all three usages on the first page of my Google Books search. Partly the result of studying English as used over many centuries to degree level, and having lived through many decades of "usage shifts over time" myself, I take all notions of "correctness" with a large pinch of salt. Correct according to who? *When?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question was: What would you rather **her** do.

Comment: No it isn't. Read the question again. Both the title and the bulk of the question text concern the ***do / does*** choice, not ***she / her***. But as I commented to @WS2, I don't like ***her*** at all. It sounds very "dialectal" to me.

Comment: I never said it was ungrammatical, did I? I said it wouldn't do. Not the same thing.

Answer (score -3):

This is called [causative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative).

The subject of the action/sentence is *you*, who is the cause of an action of a second person. Even though it might seem that the verb is an action that *she* will do, this is not the case. The action is done by *you*. The action is to *make her do* or *have her do*. In your case, it has been shortened to *her do*. This is the verb that *you* do.

I am not sure if the omission of the verb *make* or *have* is considered undesirable. It is definitely used as you wrote it.

It is very common to express causative value using *make/have* + *noun* + *bare infinitive*. The bare infinitive is the action that *noun* will do. In your case the *do* is the bare infinitive.

But since the sentence is really expressing an action of its subject *you*, it would be the verb *make/have* the one that carries the declination by person. For example:

> She makes her do.

Because some are confused about it. - There are many ways in which a sentence can have causative value. Your example is but one of them. Causative value can be constructed also using *have* + *noun* + *past participle* as in

> She had him killed.

Comment: good ... add a dictionary or similar citation.

Comment: This seems more like a subjunctive situation. I'd rewrite the OP's question as: "What would you rather she do?"

Comment: @user888379 Causative and subjunctive are not exclusive categories. The former is [valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)), while the latter is [mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood).  What you wrote is still causative. Moreover, mood doesn't explain why *do* remains as infinitive. The fact that causative is constructed as [*make/have*] + noun + *bare infinitive verb* does tell what is the construction being used. His sentence is correct. Changing it would avoid even more answering his question.

Comment: *I would rather she do/did/does* is not causative. It doesn't mean *I would rather make her do ...*

Comment: @PeterShor You are simply wrong about that. That is a sentence with causative value too.

Comment: *I would rather the sun was shining* does not mean *I would rather make the sun shine*.

Comment: @PeterShor The wish has also causative value. That is independent on whether or not you believe, or whether it makes sense or not that a wish can be a cause. After all, causation is always postulated.

Comment: I agree that the subjunctive is correct.  But if a contrary action has been completed, the past subjunctive would be used "What would you rather she had done?"  If a contrary action is ongoing, "What would you rather she were doing?" Otherwise, if there is no counterfactual element, "What would you rather she do?"

Comment: I don't get the example "She makes her do.". She makes her do what? It doesn't seem grammatical at all, nor does it make  sense as a non-grammatical counter-example.

Comment: I think unquestionably @user888379 has the right of it here. Most "careful" speakers / writers would still use subjunctive ***do*** in such contexts. But the subjunctive is increasingly falling out of favour, and there's nothing particularly "unusual" about the usage as cited. Past Tense ***did*** is also a common "acceptable" alternative to the subjunctive, along with Present Tense ***does***. (Unless you're a grammar nazi looking for something to vent your spleen on! :)