# American English. Please help me identify the correct form of 'become' in the following sentence:

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conjugation

> I'm sure we'd all rather I became a bit more self-sufficient.

Using *became* feels right, but I would appreciate anyone who could explain what's going on grammatically here. I think *become* is in the subjunctive, so maybe most correctly I should say

> I'm sure we'd all rather that I become a bit more self-sufficient.

Is *that* strictly necessary? And regarding my original construction:
am I wrong to feel so right?

Comment: Why earth should it be just one tense and not the other? They mean different things. Use the right one for the right purpose. "rather I became" is not the same as "rather I become," though the former is the more common.

Comment: That's a good point. Do you mind explaining to me the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["would rather" + subject + past subjunctive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169250/would-rather-subject-past-subjunctive) [This thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371727/syntax-of-would-rather) covers perhaps a more clearly related example, but was itself closed as a duplicate.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/verb-patterns/would-rather-would-sooner) only licenses the [different referent (subject) plus past simple clause] variant, but in the US the 'mandative subjunctive-or-is-it' is usually preferred.

Comment: It's not subjunctive since "would rather" does not license subjunctive clauses. "Would rather" can take a finite clause, either present tense with "become" as in your second example, or past tense with the modal preterite "became" as in your first example. That" is optional, but (I believe) usually omitted. Incidentally, "would rather" is in competition with "would prefer", also taking a finite clause complement

Comment: Note that the subjunctive is only distinct with "be" or a 3rd person singular subject, neither of which is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

*Became* is the past (historically, the "past subjunctive", but that is different for precisely one word in the language: *were* vs *was*). It is normally used for counterfactual conditionals, like yours. So yes, *became* is exactly what I would expect there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great question, and you may get a lot of rather technical answers. My quick take: use either; they're both OK, though I prefer "become" because "become" is the subjunctive here (well, it's often called that, though some argue English doesn't have a subjunctive). Using "became" turns the sentence into a conditional, which would be fine if you used "if" instead of "that": "I'm sure we'd all rather [if] I became a bit more self-sufficient."